# Dimension Theorem modification

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, alternative-proof

The Dimension Theorem says 
$$
\dim(U+W) = \dim(U) + \dim(W) - \dim(U \cap W)
$$

The proof of this theorem uses the bases of $U$, $W$, and $U\cap W$.

Is it possible to prove this theorem with just spanning lists of the three vector spaces or the spanning list of $U \cap W$ and linearly independent lists of $U$ and $W$ instead of using bases?

Comment: To count spanning lists etc , you need at some point, the vectors you are counting are linearly independent (to avoid double counting) and you do not leave any vector out (it is a spanning set). This is just an indirect way of using the basis. Also, note that the very definition of dimension needs the concept of basis (and the remarkable fact that the number of vectors in a finite basis is independent of the basis).